# Run JS on appended html with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I want to recreate the following using angularJS.

```
  <div>
    <fieldset class="regulated">
        <legend>This list was created with html</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Category1</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h5>Element1</h5>
                        <p>Description of Category 1 Element 1</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h5>Element2</h5>
                        <p>Description of Category 1 Element 2</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h5>Element1</h5>
                        <p>Description of Category 1 Element 3</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Element2</h4>
                <p>Description of element 2</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Category2</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h5>Element1</h5>
                        <p>Description of Category 2 Element 1</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h5>Element2</h5>
                        <p>Description of Category 2 Element 2</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is how I tried and what I have achieved till now.
This is the html on which my controller is called.

```
 <div>
    <fieldset class="regulated" ng-controller="UlController2">
        <legend>{{information.header}}</legend>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
                <div ng-bind-html="element(item.followUp)"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And this is the controller I am using.

```
 app.controller('UlController2', function($scope,$sce) {
    $scope.information = {
        header : "This list was created with angular!"
    };
    $scope.items = [
        {'name' : 'Category1', 'followUp' : '<ul></ul>'},
        {'name' : 'Element2', 'followUp' : '<p>Description of element 2</p>'},
        {'name' : 'Category2', 'followUp' : '<ul></ul>'}
    ];
    $scope.elEments = [
        {'name':'Element1','description':'Description of Category 1 Wlement 1'},
        {'name':'Element2','description':'Description of Category 1 Wlement 2'},
        {'name':'Element3','description':'Description of Category 1 Wlement 3'},
    ];
    $scope.element = function(input){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
});
```

I want to make this without any JQuery or native JavaScript, only AngularJS native methods.

Comment: How do you imagine it'd know what categories you have, when you didn't define them?

Comment: You are totally right. I didn't copy the object that contains the category info. The object items is the one that contains them.
I dont know how to move forward from this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions, both written in angular 1.3.8. 
The first is based on Marcel's answer and the other is mine.

This is based on Marcel:

```js
app.controller('UlController2', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.information = {
    header: "This 2nd list was created with angular!"
  };
  $scope.items = [{
    'name': 'Category1',
    'innerList': [{
      'name': 'Element1',
      'description': 'Description of Category 1 Element 1'
    }, {
      'name': 'Element2',
      'description': 'Description of Category 1 Element 2'
    }, {
      'name': 'Element3',
      'description': 'Description of Category 1 Element 3'
    }, ]
  }, {
    'name': 'Element2',
    'followUp': 'Description of element 2'
  }, {
    'name': 'Category2',
    'innerList': [{
      'name': 'Element1',
      'description': 'Description of Category 2 Element 1'
    }, {
      'name': 'Element2',
      'description': 'Description of Category 2 Element 2'
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <fieldset class="regulated long">
    <legend>This 2nd list was created with html</legend>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h4>Category1</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5>Element1</h5>
            <p>Description of Category 1 Element 1</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h5>Element2</h5>
            <p>Description of Category 1 Element 2</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h5>Element1</h5>
            <p>Description of Category 1 Element 3</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4>Element2</h4>
        <p>Description of element 2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4>Category2</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5>Element1</h5>
            <p>Description of Category 2 Element 1</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h5>Element2</h5>
            <p>Description of Category 2 Element 2</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div>
  <fieldset class="regulated long" ng-controller="UlController2">
    <legend>{{information.header}}</legend>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
        <p>{{item.followUp}}</p>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="Li in item.innerList">
            <h5>{{Li.name}}</h5>
            <p>{{Li.description}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

And this is mine, simulating the reading of a JSON response.

```js
app.controller('UlController3', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.information = {
    header: "This 3rd list was created with angular!"
  };
  var items = [{
    'name': 'Category1',
    'innerList': [{
      'name': 'Element1',
      'description': 'Description of Category 1 Element 1'
    }, {
      'name': 'Element2',
      'description': 'Description of Category 1 Element 2'
    }]
  }, {
    'name': 'Element2',
    'followUp': 'Description of element 2'
  }];
  $scope.innerUl = function() {
    var toAdd = '';
    var inner = '';
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
      angular.forEach(value, function(firstLiVal, key) {
        if (key == 'name') {
          toAdd += '<li><h4>' + firstLiVal + '</h4>';
        } else if (key == 'followUp') {
          toAdd += '<p>' + firstLiVal + '</p></li>';
        } else if (key == 'innerList') {
          angular.forEach(firstLiVal, function(SecondUlVal, key) {
            angular.forEach(SecondUlVal, function(SecondLiVal, key) {
              if (key == 'name') {
                inner += '<li><h5>' + SecondLiVal + '</h5>';
              } else {
                inner += '<p>' + SecondLiVal + '</p></li>';
              }
            });
          });
          toAdd += '<ul>' + inner + '</ul></li>';
        }
      });
    });
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(toAdd);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <fieldset class="regulated long">
    <legend>This 3rd list was created with html</legend>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h4>Category1</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5>Element1</h5>
            <p>Description of Category 1 Element 1</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h5>Element2</h5>
            <p>Description of Category 1 Element 2</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4>Element2</h4>
        <p>Description of element 2</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div>
  <fieldset class="regulated long" ng-controller="UlController3">
    <legend>{{information.header}}</legend>
    <ul ng-bind-html='innerUl()'></ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the data you have there because you have no information about the category. It's also difficult for us because your variables names in the controller do not match the ones in the view. Other than that, given you have the information about the category you can do it with two nested `ng-repeat`.

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.categories = [
          {
            name: 'Category 1',
            items: [
              {
                name: 'Element1',
                description: 'Description of Category 1 Element 1'
              }, 
              {
                name: 'Element2',
                description: 'Description of Category 1 Element 2'
              }, 
              {
                name: 'Element3',
                description: 'Description of Category 1 Element 3'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'Category 2',
            items: [
              {
                name: 'Element1',
                description: 'Description of Category 2 Element 1'
              }, 
              {
                name: 'Element2',
                description: 'Description of Category 2 Element 2'
              }, 
              {
                name: 'Element3',
                description: 'Description of Category 2 Element 3'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <fieldset class="regulated">
    <legend>This list was created with angular</legend>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <h4>{{category.name}}</h4>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in category.items">
            <h5>{{item.name}}</h5>
            <p>{{item.description}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't give you all the script. I mistakenly removed the object that contained the needed info.

Comment: Would it be a lot of trouble to update your answer for category 1 and category 2 as I given them?
Thanks for your trouble!

Comment: To be honest I don't get how you want to link the categories and the elements. There is nothing in your data that would allow you to tell which element belongs to which category.

Comment: I want to append the object elements after the category 1 header. I created a div where I place a ul with trust. I was planning to use ng-repeat again and populate the ul with the object elements. There I was stuck. Seeing your answer again I believe that I understood how to solve my problem.